# Using template in linked list

Tags: c++, templates

I came across this problem,, i need to implement a linked list, but the data type of element stored in the node may a string or a pointer to another class,

```
class Node{
    public:
        string data;
        void *link;
        Node *next;

        Node(){
            link = next = NULL;
        }
        Node(string str){
            data = str;
        }
        Node(void *ptr){
            link = ptr;
        }
};

class List{
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;

    public:
        void insert(string str){
            Node *newNode = new Node(str);
            /* ... */
        }
        void insert(void *ptr){
            Node *newNode = new Node(ptr);
            /* ... */
        }
};
```

I try to use template but i couldn't, how could i use template for this ?

Comment: Should a `List` be capable of holding some strings and some pointers mixed, or should there be separate types for list-of-strings and list-of-pointers?  What went wrong when you tried a template way?

Comment: i want list-of-strings And list-of-pointers separated,, when I tried it, compiler gave me a list of errors :p

Comment: Is this homework?  Is there a reason to not `#include <list>`?

Comment: I suggest that you start by creating a list-of-int just to make sure you can get all the list operations working. After you are confident that your list-of-int class doesn't have any bugs, then change it to a templated class that can use any type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The STL has a `std::list` templated class, you really should use it.  But if you want to implement your own class then try something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Node
{ 
public: 
    Node *next; 
    T data; 

    Node(const T &value)
        : next(NULL), data(value)
    {
    } 
}; 

template<typename T>
class List
{ 
private:
    Node<T> *head; 
    Node<T> *tail; 

public: 
    List()
        : head(NULL), tail(NULL)
    {
    }

    void insert(const T &value)
    { 
        Node<T> *newNode = new Node<T>(value); 
        if (!head)
            head = newNode;
        if (tail)
            tail->next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    } 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially do something like this:

```
template <class T>
class List 
{
public:
    List(): root(NULL) {};
    ~List();
    bool add(const T& item);
    ....

private:
    typedef struct Node {
        T item;
        struct Node *next;
    } Node; 
    Node *root;
};
```

It would be interesting to see other answers to this.
C++ is not my strongest topic, but this example should compile and work. You know that in C++ struct is sort of "public-by-default" class so you can even include functions in it (I would rather add private functions to your list instead though).

Comment: Personally, I would construct an empty `List` with `root` initialized to `NULL`.  That way you can tell the difference between an empty list and a list with single default-constructed element.  Other than that, you have a great start.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Max. I've adjusted the post. You are right and I would do the same as well.